# "Like" Button is liking an older version of my url

Tags: facebook, url, facebook-like

The URL of my website was recently redirecting to another site who happen to have their own Facebook profile.
I have just uploaded a website to that URL consequently stopping the redirecting.

I have placed a "Like" Button on this website but it is liking the site my URL was once redirecting to and not my actual URL.

Anyone have an idea of how I can make it so its liking my URL instead?

The code definitely includes my URL and not the other one, I have cleared my cache and so on, I have re-uploaded the Like Button several times with different methods all to no avail.

Would really appreciate if someone would be kind enough to help,
Thank you.

Comment: What does [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) say?